# select a value from one table and insert to another table

Tags: asp.net, sql, silverlight

I have two tables in a database and I want to select one value from one of that table. For that I want to pass one value and if that value stored in the table I want pick the id representing the value in the next table.

That means the operation is that first I select a row of data from first table by using a user control in that row there is a value (example "apple") and I want pass that value("apple") to the second table. In the second table the value ("apple") having a id (example "australian") and I want that the query search for that id ("australian") and show that in the text box.

Example

first table

```
id name details
1 apple sweet
2 orange sweet
```

second Table

```
id           name     details
Australian   apple      sold
Indian       banana     sold
```

Imagine that this is the two tables using a usercontrol I select first a row from first table and I want to pass that value "apple" to second table and find out the id of "australian" (that is equivalent id for apple in the second tabl ) from the second table and show that in a text box.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a very simple select statement.  Something like:

```
SELECT id FROM second_table s
INNER JOIN first_table f ON f.name = s.name
WHERE f.name ='apple'
```

But unless you need to confirm it exists in the first table why not just select it from the second:

```
SELECT id FROM second_table 
WHERE name ='apple'
```

Comment: any other method from any one else?